# Variable declaration not allowed here, used in if statement

Tags: java

After typing that first part of the if statement, I was going to use the next line to declare a variable (costPerCD) but I'm told "Variable declaration is not allowed here." I'm not sure how else to calculate the costPerCD without using this method. This is an example of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    if ((numCDs>=1 && (numCDs<=4))
    double costPerCD= 20.99;
```

Comment: To serve what purpose? That variable is only visible within that if block and nowhere else.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I use it other places, the code is pretty lengthy, I can still post all of it if you'd like but it's really not relevant to the question.

Comment: But don't you see -- you **can't** use it in other places if you declare it there. Learn about variable scope to see why. Then declare the variable before that block.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, I don't see.

Comment: **Again** read on variable scope. You're declaring it: `if (foo) {double bar = 1.0;}`. The bar variable is only visible within the `{}` curly braces. You have no braces, but that one line is its own block of code, and its the same as if you surrounded it in curly braces. Read the tutorials on scope. Now. You won't regret this.

Comment: That code shouldn't cause that error. Rather it will show the warning: "The value of the local variable costPerCD is not used". Please post a small program that shows the error to us.

Comment: Don't replace your question with a different one. If you have another question to ask, ask it separately.

Comment: @shmosel Man I can't.

Comment: These errors are all very easy to look up. Please do so and you'll save yourself much grief and learn a lot of Java in the process.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels:
It is interesting to note that. at the moment, the declaration is not objected by IntelliJ IDE if it is surrounded by flower braces like: 
```if(x > y) {int i=1;}``` 
While it is objected and error is spit if the curly braces are removed: 
```if(x>y) int i=1;```
Weird.
P.S. Haven't tested in any other IDEs. Came across this behavior and wanted to share along.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare that variable as a class variable. Then you can access the variable throughout your class.

You need to add an additional ")" to your code after your first condition. This should prevent the error you are getting.

```
public class CDCal {
    //Class Variable can be accessed in this class
    private costPerCD;

    public CDCal(){
        //Assign value when object created
        costPerCD = 20.99
    }

    public double calculateCost(int numCDs){
        double total = 0;
        if((numCDs >= 1) && (numCDs <= 4))
        {
            //Calculate total cost of CD's based on number and price
            total = costPerCD * numCDs;
        }
        //Return the total at the end of the method.
        Return total;

}
```

If you have an example I will be happy to review it to help you out.

Comment: Nevermind. It works actually. I just have a different error. :(...

Comment: What is the error?